# can't use other port for nodejs application unless I sudo

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, port

Hi I have a fairly simple Nodejs program , I want to demonstrate on a small scale what "microservices" look like.

So I want to run a couple separate Node servers on different ports on my local machine, however when I change the port number to 3001 it stops working. After I run the command with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo node index.js` it starts working with the specified port (3001). Here is my index.js file.

(By "working" I mean that I can send a GET / POST request to the various routes, when it "doesn't work" I don't get any response back even though the server is running)

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

//import routes
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts');

const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(express.json());

//route middlewares
app.use('/api/user', postRoute);

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Server Running...'))
```

./routes/post.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello sir!"); 
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what happens when you run `node index.js` ? is there any error?

Comment: no error, the line Server Running prints on the console but then I can't make any requests

Comment: Have you tried with other ports as well ? Try different port in the range of 10k and above, usually they are neither privileged port nor well known ports.

Comment: Are you running the additional service in another terminal/shell tab via node index.js when you change the port? You need a new process for each node instance you want to run.

Comment: yes I am, its running fine but none of the requests go through

Answer (score 0):

This sounds unusual. What happens if you try it without the `verifytoken` middleware? There may be a file permissions issue with a file that the middleware relies on - maybe a secret key?

Comment: whoops! let me take that out, that was from another file that I was using but its not really important I think in this question

Comment: Make a minimal reproducer project with nothing else in it, only what you posted here. Does it behave the same way?

Comment: I made a project with JUST these two files (and a package.json) and yeah I still cannot get a response back from a request

Comment: Firewall settings? 

What's the address you are connecting to? Is it http://127.0.0.1:3001? 

What OS is this?

Comment: I am connecting to localhost:3001 I am using a Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, it wasn't anything to do with Node or permissions. Postman by default enables proxying through localhost:3000, so when I curled using the appropriate command I could get to the application but through postman it wasn't working.